# How do i reduce the uploading time of image in cloudinary from node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I am uploading image from node js to cloudinary. it takes to 4 to 5 seconds to upload a single image to cloudinary. i uploaded multiple image at a time it tak 12 seconds for 2 or 3 images. i want to reduce the time of uploading to 200 ms to 400ms .How i can achieve this?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: '../uploads'
});
const upload = multer({ storage })

cloudinary.uploader.upload(item.path, { unique_filename: true, folder: "Shop" }, (error, data) => {
                if (error) {
                    next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400))
                    return reject({ error })
                }
                else {
                    return resolve(data.secure_url)
                }
            })
```

Comment: Upload time would depend on file size and network speed.

Answer (score 0):

As ch4nd4n said, the upload time would depend on the file size and network speed. However, it is unlikely that you could get request times for even small images and a fast network, to consistently take 200-400 ms given latency and processing times. Having tested an upload using the Cloudinary Node.js SDK just now, it took 569 ms to upload a 300 kb image with 400 mbps upload speeds.

Comment: Ya, checked it yesterday, it took me to 3 to 4 seconds of any image size. As you mention about network speed. I can view full HD video on the web.